# Setup consul UI on Kubernetes + nginx ingress controller on path "/consul" instead of "/"

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, consul

This may sound like a repeat question and I checked some similar answers but not sure what is going wrong with my setup, so asking this question here. (referred [issue#758](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-helm/issues/758) and tried solution but not working for me).
I am sure I am doing something wrong - someone please help me.

**What I have so far:**

- Have a k8s cluster with metallb load balancer and nginx ingress controller already setup.

**What I expect:**

- With helm installation of consul, I need to setup consul ingress in such a way that the UI path should be:  `myweb.mydommain.com/consul`

**What's happening:**

- After setup on consul, if I visit browser and type: myweb.mydomain.com/consul - I get following error:
  `Invalid URL path: if attempting to use the HTTP API, ensure the path starts with '/v1/'`
- But, If I change the "path" directive of consul ingress values in values.yaml from "/consul" to "/", then `myweb.mydomain.com` shows me consul UI without any issues.

**My setup:**
K8s version:

```
 $ kubectl version
 Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.10", GitCommit:"a7a32748b5c60445c4c7ee904caf01b91f2dbb71", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-02-16T11:24:04Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.14", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
 Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.10", GitCommit:"a7a32748b5c60445c4c7ee904caf01b91f2dbb71", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-02-16T11:18:16Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.14", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

nginx and consul helm charts:

```
$ helm list -A (Trimmed output)
 NAME                   NAMESPACE               REVISION    UPDATED                                 STATUS      CHART                                   APP VERSION
 consul                 consul                  1           2022-08-22 19:42:43.496703951 +0000 UTC deployed    consul-0.46.1                           1.12.3
 nginx-stable           nginx-stable            1           2022-08-03 22:33:45.242779695 +0000 UTC deployed    nginx-ingress-0.14.0                    2.3.0
```

consul values.yaml for helm installation:

```
global:
  name: consul
ui:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    hosts:
    - backend:
        port:
          name: 80
        service:
          name: consul-ui
      host: myweb.mydomain.com
      pathType: ImplementationSpecific
      paths:
      - /consul
    ingressClassName: nginx
```

Alternate/similar command line consul install with above values (without values.yaml file):

```
helm install consul hashicorp/consul --set global.name=consul \
                                     --create-namespace --namespace consul \
                                     --set ui.ingress.enabled=true \
                                     --set 'ui.ingress.hosts[0].host=myweb.mydomain.com' \
                                     --set 'ui.ingress.hosts[0].paths[0]=/consul' \
                                     --set 'ui.ingress.ingressClassName=nginx' \
                                     --set 'ui.ingress.hosts[0].backend.service.name=consul-ui' \
                                     --set 'ui.ingress.hosts[0].backend.port.name=80' \
                                     --set 'ui.ingress.hosts[0].pathType=ImplementationSpecific'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Please help.